# Snowflake table stage data loading

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to load data into table using table stage, but when I try to query from the table, it is giving an error such as no such column present.

```
Copy into Table name from @/table stage id
```

```
update Employee  set first name='Neha' where first name='Arjun';
```

e.g Employee table has column such as first name and need to change value from Arjun to Neha

**it gives an error " SQL COMPILATION ERROR: syntax error line 1 at position 2 unexpected 'name' "**

Any restriction with table stage?

Comment: Would you be able to share the command you used and the error message you got?

Comment: I staged file via web UI then I get stage ID - Command I used  copy into table name from @/ stage id; and IF I try to Perform DML command such as update for a column value where clause is mentioned then it gives an error " unexpected column name"

Comment: Please update your question (don’t put it in a comment) with the exact statement that is causing the error. You’ve given a COPY INTO statement but then said that some different DML statement, that you haven’t shown, gives an error

Comment: Share exact statement you are using and error. The one you have shared is not correct syntactically - "update table name alter first name set first name='abc' where first name='xyz';

Comment: Object names can’t contain spaces, so you cannot have a column called “first name”

Answer (score 1):

[Object identifier](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html) rules

### *insert doc's here*

> Unquoted object identifiers:
>
> - Start with a letter (A-Z, a-z) or an underscore (“_”).
> - Contain only letters, underscores, decimal digits (0-9), and dollar signs (“$”).
> - Are stored and resolved as uppercase characters (e.g. id is stored and resolved as ID).
>
> If you put double quotes around an identifier (e.g. “My identifier with blanks and punctuation.”), the following rules apply:
>
> - The case of the identifier is preserved when storing and resolving the identifier (e.g. "id" is stored and resolved as id).
> - The identifier can contain and can even start with any ASCII character from the blank character (32) to the tilde (126).
>
> To use the double quote character inside a quoted identifier, use two quotes. For example:
>
> ```
> create table "quote""andunquote""" ...
> ```
>
> creates a table named:
>
> ```
> quote"andunquote"
> ```
>
> where the quotation marks are part of the name.

Phew,

### So some testing of that:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(first_name string);
```

| status |
| --- |
| Table TABLE_NAME successfully created. |

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(first name string);
```

> Syntax error: unexpected 'name'. (line 8)

```
CREATE TABLE table name(first_name string);
```

> Syntax error: unexpected 'table'. (line 12)
>
> syntax error line 1 at position 23 unexpected '('. (line 12)

```
CREATE TABLE "table name"(first_name string);
```

| status |
| --- |
| Table table name successfully created. |

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "table name"("first name" string);
```

| status |
| --- |
| Table table name successfully created. |

### Thus for you code:

```
Copy into "Table name" from @/"table stage id";
```

and

```
update Employee set "first name"='Neha' where "first name"='Arjun';
```